# How can I remove audio source from a file with the audio source itself?

Tags: software, music, audacity, instruments

Example:
User has a audio file named A with multiple instruments
The multipe instruments are : Drums, piano, bass, sax.

User also has a audio file named B of an single instrument.
The single instrument is : piano.

The piano from audio file A is identical As the audio file from file B.

Question:

Can audio file B be used to mute the piano from File A ?

I prefer Audacity ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, invert the phase of part B, whilst making sure it is perfectly lined up, timing-wise. Play both simultaneously. Bounce.

Different EQ (in particular, though to a lesser extent - other processing, such as harmonic distortion...) having been applied to A and B will interfere with your ability to completely null the instrument in question.